# After loading an app to the iOS Appstore is it possible to make it active / public from a specified date?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to load my app to the appstore and make it public in order to sell but not immediately,  for example lets say in 1 month. Is there any option that makes it possible?

I need to install a weather station in a month  but before I want to finish all the procedures for the appstore, so that directly after the installation I can be able to present the related app on the appstore.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set the availability date:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options.
either you upload your app and set it for "developer release", so you have to release it after its through the appstore, or you set the options for availability in the "Rights and Prizing" part.